# change href depending on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I have button for which I need href value depending upon window width. href value should be updated when page load as well as on window resize.

**[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lafawusi/1/edit)**

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="myButton js-button">Google</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(function(){

      function mobileButtonLink(){

          var mobLoginLink = 'https://mobile.google.com',          
              $loginButton = $('.js-button'),                    
              storedLoginLink = $loginButton.attr('href'),          
              winwidth = $(window).width();    

        if (winwidth < 600) {
          $loginButton.attr('href', mobLoginLink);
          console.log(mobLoginLink);
        }else{
          console.log(storedLoginLink);
          $loginButton.attr('href', storedLoginLink); 

        } 
      } 

      mobileButtonLink();

      $(window).resize(mobileButtonLink);


    });
```

in greater than 600 its not getting updated by old href value if page is loaded in below 600 viewport. Is there any better way to achieve this by using revealing pattern etc.

Comment: why don't you add responsive media queries to achieve this instead of controlling by using javascript?

Comment: @MaheshSapkal media queries are entirely possible in JS thanks to the matchMedia API, and suit this task better than CSS. See my answer below which uses my enquire lib to do exactly that (in a slightly nicer way than underlying matchMedia API)

Comment: You can solve that in plain CSS by providing different links in the HTML – one for each breakpoint – and display only the relevant links based on a media query.

Comment: @WickyNilliams - if you can prove that, I'll be impressed. Looking at the [**source**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/master/dist/enquire.js) for your plugin I can't really imagine that it would be any faster than just listening for window.onresize, there's quite a bit of custom event handling going on.

Comment: @adeneo resize events can fire very frequently, typically you would debounce/throttle it (much like scroll events). the browser itself manages events for matchMedia (they only fire when something changes), so is bound to be better performing. the only event handling i do is matchMedia(mq).addListener(fn), it's not custom at all :)

Comment: @Mahesh - this is beacause I want to keep HTML markup as minimum as possible.I have got another solution <a class="js-login" data-desktop-url="https://google.com" href="https://google.com">google</a> so data-desktop-url I can use in desktop breakpoint instead two separate anchor tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simpler, just toggle the hrefs based on the window width on resize, and trigger the resize on load

```
$(function(){
  var hrefs = [$('.js-button').attr('href'), 'https://mobile.google.com'];

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.js-button').attr('href', function() {
      return hrefs[$(window).width() < 600 ? 0 : 1];
    });
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/lafawusi/8/edit)

Comment: it looks great with minimal code but can we make hrefs array dynamic instead putting static href values- thanks

Comment: @PravinVaichal - like that ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out my lib [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) which is meant for just this sort of thing. It uses media queries instead of reading window width. It will perform better than listening to raw resize events because the browser only fires media query events when needed.

```
enquire.register("(max-width: 600px)", {
    urls : {
        mobile : "https://mobile.google.com"
    },

    setup : function() {
        this.link = document.querySelector("a");
        this.urls.original = this.link.href;
    },

    match : function() {
        this.link.href = this.urls.mobile;
    },

    unmatch : function() {
        this.link.href = this.urls.original;
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/WickyNilliams/6p0Lz7xa/

Comment: it works fine but with this solution I need to integrate enquire.js as additional library, but this way we can handle scenarios and with better performance thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Store the original href value outside the function:

```
$(function(){
   storedLoginLink = $('.js-button').attr('href')  // <----|
  function mobileButtonLink(){                          // | 
      var mobLoginLink = 'https://mobile.google.com',   // |       
          $loginButton = $('.js-button'),      // ---------|
          winwidth = $(window).width();    

    if (winwidth < 600) {
      $loginButton.attr('href', mobLoginLink);
      console.log(mobLoginLink);
    }else{
      $loginButton.attr('href', storedLoginLink); 

    } 
  } 

  mobileButtonLink();

  $(window).resize(mobileButtonLink);


});
```